# Get text after 2 spans with XPath/lxml?

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I have a HTML source that looks like

```
<span class="review-title">first text</span> second text
```

I'm working in python. I can get the "first text" by calling

```
tree.xpath('//span[@class="review-title"]/text()')
```

I'm wondering how do I get the "second text" also using xpath? I'm new to this and would appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: from you snippet. the 'second text'  is not in a span tag. It is in the parent tag (e.g div) or a text node (i.e. no tag). Identifying which one of the two will help with composing an xpath

Comment: Also, i suggest looking int Beautiful for parsing html

Comment: My team is not using beautiful soup, any idea how to use xpath?

Answer (score 0):

Just use **following-sibling::text()**

XPath:

```
'//span[@class="review-title"]/following-sibling::text()'
```

**UPDATE:**

To join strings you can use concat function

XPath 1.0

```
"concat(//span[@class='review-title']/text(), //span[@class='review-title']/following-sibling::text())"
```

Comment: Hi Again. Would you happen to know how to pair up the "first text" and "second test"?? Right now, tree.xpath('//span[@class="review-title"]/text()') and tree.xpath*'//span[@class="review-title"]/following-sibling::text()') gives me 2 separate lists. I want to be able to pair up first text with the corresponding second text, in one list if possible. Thanks!